# Deserializing a string line by line in C

Tags: c

I'm receiving as string in the following format over a UDP connection

```
1 2 7
1 3 5
1 4 6
```

I want to deserialize this string and write it into an array of structs of the following type

```
typedef struct RV{
    int server1;
    int server2;
    int weight;
}RV;
```

I'm using the following function to do that.

```
void deserialize(RV** arr, char* msg){
    int idx = 0;
    char line[10];

    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, msg)){
        RV rv;
        rv.server1 = atoi(strtok(line, " "));
        rv.server2 = atoi(strtok(NULL, " "));
        rv.weight = atoi(strtok(NULL,"\n"));
        memcpy(arr[idx], &rv, sizeof(rv));
        idx++;
    }

}
```

I continue to get a `segmentation fault` when I try to read this array.

Comment: How do you call `deserialize`?

Comment: By passing an array which has been malloced and string also which has been malloced.

Comment: Why do you pass an array as a double pointer then? It should be either `RV arr[]` or `RV *arr`.

Comment: Because the array holds pointers to the RV type.

Comment: Did you allocate the individual elements as well?

Comment: What does your debugger tell you? And what/where exactly is the code that does: "when I try to read this array"? And have you verified for sure that input is indeed valid strings as expected?

Comment: Yes I've allocated space for individual RV types.

Comment: It looks like the fgets in breaking the code.

Comment: There's no need to guess. Run your program in a debugger and it will tell you precisely.

Comment: Oh, just noticed that your `fgets` call is incorrect. The last parameter is supposed to be a `FILE *` not a `char *`. Surely your compiler screamed to you about that? Always wise to listen to the compiler's warnings.

Comment: Yup I do get a warning, but cant figure out another way to read a string line by line. Any suggestions.

Comment: Also rechecked on gdb, that is the line that seems to be breaking the code.

Comment: Argh! You got a warning on that very line of code, you saw the warning, you consciously ignored it and you didn't think that was worth sharing with us to save us time? There are many ways to do what you want. `strtok` is one way. Just an extension of what you are already doing within the line.

Comment: How do I check strtok on a NULL

Comment: Rather how do I use strtok to read the string line by line.

Comment: Get rid of the `fgets`. Store the return value of the last `strtok`. If it is NULL then finished. If not NULL just continue - your existing `strtok` calls already parse it line by line.

Comment: You mean while(strtok(NULL, "\n") != NULL)

Answer (score 0):

> Yup I do get a warning, but cant figure out another way to read a
>   string line by line. Any suggestions.

You could change

```
    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, msg)){
```

to

```
    int n;
    while (sscanf(msg, "%9[^\n]\n%n", line, &n) > 0)
    {
        msg += n;
```

This drops the `\n`, but we don't need them anyway.